# How to get a value from a dropdown and the value will be automatically pass to another form?

Tags: laravel, dropdown

I have a dropdown button for my table. Each rows has dropdowns. So after I select the NEW option in my dropdown button, it will redirect to my route /link. How to the pass the purchase_group_id to my /link form?

I'm new to laravel. thanks

````
<button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle btn-sm" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">ADD MEMBER</button>
<div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
<a class="dropdown-item" name="purchase_group_id"href="/link" value="{{$product->purchase_group_id}}" type="submit">NEW</a>
<a class="dropdown-item" href="#">RENEWAL</a>
</div></div>```
````

Comment: You could either make it a proper form that makes a POST or GET request and redirects from there, or you could use JavaScript to append the selected group to the URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you must make a route that has a parameter on it like this :

```
Route::get('/link/{purchase_group_id}, 'YourController@index');
```

Then you can use your route link this :

```
<a class="dropdown-item" name="purchase_group_id" href="/link/{{$product->purchase_group_id}}" type="submit">NEW</a>
```

In your controller pass the parameter to next form :

```
public function index($purchase_group_id)
{
    return view('next_form')->with(compact('purchase_group_id'));
}
```

Then in your view, you can use `$purchase_group_id` variable for your form.

Comment: Yes it worked! But my css didn't work at all? how to fix this?

Comment: ah, for that maybe you need to ask a new question about css, but let I guess did you already `@extend` the view to your layout view?

Comment: Nope. I didn't used the @extend. I just forgot to use the assets on my links. It's okay now. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

You can append the selected id to the url, and handle it from your route controller.

```
<a class="dropdown-item" href="/link/{{$product->purchase_group_id}}">NEW</a>
```

This will be passed on as a GET request. If you need a POST request, you should use a form.